# Scroll top undefined in shopify site

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I am working on an ecommerce store(shopify/liuquid).

I want to scroll smoothly to different hashs.

Now because this is a CMS, I have had to add some attributes via editor or manually with JS.

Here I give it the href

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hero__cta").addClass("scroll");
    $(".hero__cta").attr("href", "#section2")
});
```

If you go to the website, just under the main image, @the new entries@ title, has this is the markup:

```html
<a id="section2"> </a>
```

And here is the JS function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top}, 800,
                function() {                
                window.location.hash = hash;
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

So if you go to the site and click on the CTA button, it should scroll smoothly to that anchor. Works on a Codepen etc, but not on the Shopify platform.

I get :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.

The site is live here:

https://www.toptrendshopping.com/

Oh and how and where do I add an IntersectionObserver polifill for this?

Comment: If you are trying to bind to dynamically created HTML elements with jquery you will want to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) as a reference.

Comment: @MUlferts, that does not work either, just tried.

Comment: If I just do a console log on click, that works, but the property top is still not recognized

Comment: Slightly confused as to why you're adding classes with jQuery? Why can't you just add it in the HTML?

Comment: @SamJohnson 
I can see that you are familiar with the shopify API and Liquid.
I have added the classes via Jquery because there was no easy way via the backend. And I did not want to go and change too much in teh template files(but will d o in the future).
I would like to ask you something anyway, I want to add IDs to the dropdown menu, to get the same animated scrolling like on the CTA btn. If I change the URL in the backend, it does not work. (If you know what I mean). SO, how can I assign an ID to the dropdown LIs? The best I can think of is use queryselecor or css child ,then assign ID

Comment: @Sam, if you could just message me here then we could have a look in chat at this. Cheers

Comment: So you're changing the IDs in the theme files but it's not showing when you load the site up?

Comment: @SamJohnson, lets go in a chat room? OK?

Comment: Sure, send me a link.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix. As you can see, this works now on the live site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hero__cta").attr("href", "#two");
$('a[href*="#"]')
// Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
 .not('[href="#0"]')
 .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
     if (
     location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
    && 
    location.hostname == this.hostname
     ) {
     // Figure out element to scroll to
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
     // Does a scroll target exist?
    if (target.length) {
     // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
      event.preventDefault();
     $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000, function() {
      // Callback after animation
      // Must change focus!
       var $target = $(target);
       $target.focus();
       if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
        return false;
      } else {
        $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
        $target.focus(); // Set focus again
       };
     });
    }
}
```

});
    });

Found this on CSS tricks, still do not entirely why all this is required but work for now.

And a little extra, if you want to add a polyfill on a Shopify store, do it in the head section of the "theme.liquid" file.